# Transaction - Springboot(JHipster) - RestService: how to

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, jhipster, spring-transactions

I have a microservice created with JHipster(SpringBoot+JPA) exposing a rest api.

During a save operation over an Entity I need to manage the transaction because I must execute another update over the DB (using other Entities).

How can I do this?

Using the tradictional approach (JDBC) I got the connection and create a transaction over it, make all the queries and finally close the transaction(commit/rollback).

With JPA I have an Entity, but I find no way to specify to begin/end(manage) the transaction programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many alternatives, here are few ones:

- define a service (a class annotated with `@Service`) and annotate with `@Transactional` the public method that implements your logic
- manage transaction manually through the `EntityManager` injected into your service class constructor
- create a custom Repository

Check the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction)

Comment: Thanks. I believe in my situation the simplest way is the first one. You say @Transactional only to the public method. I'm thinking a service class (with annotation @Service) doing all the method inside it "transactional". In this situation I can put the Transactional tag over the class and not over the each method, couldn't it?

Comment: Yes you can put in on the class, my own preference is to do it per method, I find it more expressive.